# WP_Query on custom post type not displaying, multiple loops & get_template_part

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, loop, get-template-part

I'm having problems getting my testimonials to display. On page.php I have a testimonials section. So I have a loop that grabs the content for page.php, and then a get_template_part('content', 'testimonials') to get the testimonial loop.

```
<div class="grid_12 omega clearfix">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
        <hr>

    <?php endwhile; else : ?>

        <p>There were no posts :( </p>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div>

<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'testimonials' ); ?>
```

So my main loop is up there and looks like that above ^^. My testimonials loop looks like this below in content-testimonials.php:

```
<?php 

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'testimonials',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'orderby' => 'rand'
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="testimonial push_2 grid_10 clearfix">
        <blockquote>&ldquo;<?php the_field( 'testimonial' ); ?>&rdquo;</blockquote>
        <cite>&mdash;<?php the_field( 'name' ); ?></cite>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; else : ?>

    <p>There were no testimonials :( </p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I'm still quite new to Wordpress, so I can't see what I'm missing, I've been through the admin area and made sure there were testimonials, edited the custom field to display if the post type is equal to testimonial, I just can't see why it wouldn't load.

I look forward to your responses, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you forgot to check if $the_query have posts.

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'testimonials',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'orderby' => 'rand'
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="testimonial push_2 grid_10 clearfix">
        <blockquote>&ldquo;<?php the_field( 'testimonial' ); ?>&rdquo;</blockquote>
        <cite>&mdash;<?php the_field( 'name' ); ?></cite>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; else : ?>

    <p>There were no testimonials :( </p>

<?php endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

And also don't forget to reset postdata if you are running multiple queries on a page.

Comment: Beautiful! Thankyou my man! Such a pain, missed the simplest thing. Worked like a charm!

Comment: Make sure you also reset postdata on each query, if you are running multiple queries on a page. with wp_reset_postdata(); I updated my answer with this.

Comment: @JakeGabb don't forget to accept this answer :-). For info, check out the [tour] page

Comment: I didn't forget ;), but it said I have to wait 9 minutes :'(

Comment: @JakeGabb o yes, new user restictions, forgot about that, sorry. BTW Welcome to WPSE.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE @JakeGabb ;)